# How to assign an int to an int* with a method in C?

Tags: c, pointers, methods, int

I made a method that receives an int* and this value will be assign to another int*.
When I call the method, I put an integer but I receive the error of conversion.

I try to cast the int with (int*) but the program crashes.

```
add(hashTable,  8, 0);

void add(hash_table *hashTable, int *num, int value)
```

How can I assign an integer value to an int* in a method?

Comment: `int my_int = 8; add(hashTable,  &my_int, 0);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  It would be helpful to see your code that crashes; what do you cast?  It also sounds a bit as though you have an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) — what are you really trying to do?  Why did you make the method take an `int *` if you want to pass an `int`?  Do you expect to dereference the `int *` that contains 8 and access a value at address 8?  If so, you will fail on most general purpose PCs, though you _might_ (but might not) be OK on an embedded system.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should understand what `int *` means. It means you have an int somewhere in memory, and rather than copying the value of that int into a function, you pass in the address of that variable. You can't pass in the address of a variable until you first have a variable. So the simple solution is to create a variable and give that variable the value you want. Then you can just pass in the address of that variable.

```
int n = 8;
add(hashTable, &n, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

int's are integer values, and int * is a pointer to an integer.  In other words, int *  is a location in memory that points to your integer.  In order to to assign an int to an int *, you need to put the int into the memory location pointed to by int *.  To do this, you simply put the integer at the memory location pointed to by int * (assuming the memory is already allocated)

```
 int *my_pointer = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));  // allocate memory 
 *my_pointer = my_val;
```

(you must allocate memory here, or it will crash)

or

```
 int my_val = 8;  // the memory is allocated here, so you are safe
 int *my_pointer = &my_val;
```